# How can I fix variable levels for a logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm currently working on a dataset for fractures in an OAI dataset. We have 32 columns for variables that are categorical for fractures in different locations in the body. They are either "0", "1", or they are blank "".
Therefore, I'm trying to run a logistic regression between one column and the other variables.
Code:

```r
new.glm <- function(mydata) {    
  newgroup <- as.factor( mydata$V00HIPFX.x)
  inputdata <- mydata[, 39:1230]
  
  tresult <- apply(inputdata, 2, function(x, g) 
                    summary(glm(as.numeric(x) ~ g, family = "binomial", 
                    mydata))$coef[, "Pr(>|t|)"], g=as.factor(newgroup))
```

Once running  the `glm` part of the function, my error is:  `contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels`

I've tried changing the `glm` function to glm as.factor instead of as.numeric, but that gave me the error of `Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1.` I've also tried changing `g=as.factor(newgroup)` to `g=as.factor(inputdat)`, but that also didn't work.

Comment: As others will probably comment, we need a minimal reproducible example for a well written answer, that can be achieved by putting dput(head(data, some number like 50)) and copying the output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to simplify to show exactly the issue you describe.

It is possible that your depending variable is a character vector, like this

```r
# create a copy of mtcars and break the am column intentionally
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2$am <- as.character(mtcars2$am)
# replace real values by "" at rows 1,5,10 (no particular reason for these numbers)
mtcars2$am[c(1,5,10)] <- ""

# fit a logit with mpg and wt as explanatory variables for am
glm(am ~ mpg + wt, data = mtcars2, family = binomial())
```

the error will be `Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1`

however, assuming that mtcars2 is the starting point (i.e., the data comes in a "wrong" format), we can fix it

```r
# convert to factor, but changing "" to NA
mtcars2$am <- as.factor(as.integer(mtcars2$am))

# try again
glm(am ~ mpg + wt, data = mtcars2, family = binomial())
```

which returns

```r
Call:  glm(formula = am ~ mpg + wt, family = binomial(), data = mtcars2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          mpg           wt  
    23.2200      -0.2811      -5.8190  

Degrees of Freedom: 28 Total (i.e. Null);  26 Residual
  (3 observations deleted due to missingness)
Null Deviance:      39.34 
Residual Deviance: 16.56    AIC: 22.56
```